# Infinitie scroll in recyclerView go to the first element then json adapter reloaded

Tags: android, json, android-recyclerview

I implement the Infinitie scroll in RecyclerView , every thing is ok , but when json is reloaded , cursor go to the first element then , adapter is reloaded .

This is my Activity where json is parsed and adapter set to the recyclerView

`ArchiveActivity.java :`

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.majid.aparat.R;
import com.majid.aparat.adapter.ArchiveRecyclerAdapter;
import com.majid.aparat.app.AppController;
import com.majid.aparat.pojo.VideoData;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ArchiveActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // ============ Global Variables ================ //
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    List<VideoData> videoDataList = new ArrayList<VideoData>();
    RecyclerView archiveRecyclerView;
    ArchiveRecyclerAdapter adapter;
    private String after_url;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_archive);

        String TAG = ArchiveActivity.class.getSimpleName();

        setUpToolbar();

        //btn
        Button btnVideo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnVideo);
        btnVideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(ArchiveActivity.this, WatchActivity.class));
            }
        });

        sendJsonRequest();
        showPD();
        //========================= initialize recyclerView  ===========================//

        archiveRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.archiveRecylerView);

        archiveRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(ArchiveActivity.this);

        archiveRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

//        archiveRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new SlideInUpAnimator());

        archiveRecyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(linearLayoutManager) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {
                loadMore();
            }
        });

        adapter = new ArchiveRecyclerAdapter(this, videoDataList);

        archiveRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }



    //========================= send json request ===========================//
    private void sendJsonRequest() {

        //========================= get Category intent ===========================//
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String catUrl = intent.getStringExtra("category");

        String fUrl = String.format("http://www.aparat.com//etc/api/categoryvideos/%s", catUrl);

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, fUrl, (String) null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                parsJsonResponse(response);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d("TAG", error.toString());
            }
        });
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
    }

    //========================= parse json response ===========================//
    private void parsJsonResponse(JSONObject response) {

        if (response != null) {
            try {
                JSONObject ui = response.getJSONObject("ui");
                after_url =  ui.getString("pagingForward");

                JSONArray categoryViedeos = response.getJSONArray("categoryvideos");
                for (int i = 0; i < categoryViedeos.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject currentVideo = categoryViedeos.getJSONObject(i);

                    VideoData viNew = new VideoData();

                    viNew.setVideoThumbnail(currentVideo.getString("small_poster"));
                    viNew.setVideoTitle(currentVideo.getString("title"));
                    viNew.setVideoCount(currentVideo.getString("visit_cnt"));
                    viNew.setVideoDate(currentVideo.getString("sdate"));

                    videoDataList.add(viNew);
                }
                hidePD();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    //========================= setUpToolbar ===========================//
    private void setUpToolbar() {

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String catName = intent.getStringExtra("catName");

        Toolbar archiveToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.archiveToolbar);
        //Toast.makeText(this , catUrl , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        setSupportActionBar(archiveToolbar);
        archiveToolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(catName);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.mipmap.ic_left);

    }

    //========================= showPD Method ===========================//
    private void showPD() {
        if (progressDialog == null) {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("در حال بارگزاری ");
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            progressDialog.show();
        }
    }

    //========================= hidePD Method  ===========================//
    private void hidePD() {
        if (progressDialog != null) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            progressDialog = null;
        }
    }

    //========================= LoadMore for infinitie scroll  ===========================//

    private void loadMore() {
        //Toast.makeText(ArchiveActivity.this , "we are loading !!!" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        adapter = new ArchiveRecyclerAdapter(ArchiveActivity.this , videoDataList);
        archiveRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        showPD();

        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, after_url, (String)null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        hidePD();
                if (response != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject ui = response.getJSONObject("ui");
                        after_url =  ui.getString("pagingForward");

                        JSONArray categoryViedeos = response.getJSONArray("categoryvideos");
                        for (int i = 0; i < categoryViedeos.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject currentVideo = categoryViedeos.getJSONObject(i);

                            VideoData viNew = new VideoData();

                            viNew.setVideoThumbnail(currentVideo.getString("small_poster"));
                            viNew.setVideoTitle(currentVideo.getString("title"));
                            viNew.setVideoCount(currentVideo.getString("visit_cnt"));
                            viNew.setVideoDate(currentVideo.getString("sdate"));

                            videoDataList.add(viNew);
                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //Error
            }
        });
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(request);
    }

}
```

and This is the `EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener.java` :

```
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

public abstract class EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener {
    public static String TAG = EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener.class.getSimpleName();

    private int previousTotal = 0; // The total number of items in the dataset after the last load
    private boolean loading = true; // True if we are still waiting for the last set of data to load.
    private int visibleThreshold = 5; // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position before loading more.
    int firstVisibleItem, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;

    private int current_page = 1;

    private LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager;

    public EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager) {
        this.mLinearLayoutManager = linearLayoutManager;
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

        visibleItemCount = recyclerView.getChildCount();
        totalItemCount = mLinearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
        firstVisibleItem = mLinearLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

        if (loading) {
            if (totalItemCount > previousTotal) {
                loading = false;
                previousTotal = totalItemCount;
            }
        }
        if (!loading && (totalItemCount - visibleItemCount)
                <= (firstVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
            // End has been reached

            // Do something
            current_page++;

            onLoadMore(current_page);

            loading = true;
        }
    }

    public abstract void onLoadMore(int current_page);
}
```

and This is `ArchiveRecyclerAdapter.java`

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.majid.aparat.adapter.ArchiveRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder;
import com.majid.aparat.pojo.VideoData;
import com.majid.aparat.R;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by majid on 18/01/2016.
 */
public class ArchiveRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ArchiveRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    //================== Global Var
    Context context;
    List<VideoData> videoDataList ;

    //=================== Constructor  ============================= //

    public ArchiveRecyclerAdapter(Context context , List<VideoData> videoDataList) {

        this.context = context;
        this.videoDataList = videoDataList;
    }

    //===================  ViewHolder ============================= //
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        private ImageView imgThumbnailVideo;
        private TextView txtTitleVideo;
        private TextView txtCountVideo;
        private TextView txtDateVideo;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

            imgThumbnailVideo = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgThumnailVideo);
            txtTitleVideo = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtVideoTitle);
            txtDateVideo = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtVideoDate);
            txtCountVideo = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtVideoCount);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext() , txtTitleVideo.getText() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        }
    }


    //=================== OnCreateViewHolder ============================= //
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.video_item_row , null);

        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(rootView);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    //=================== onBindViewHolder ============================= //
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Context context = holder.itemView.getContext();

        VideoData currentVideoData = videoDataList.get(position);

        Glide.with(context).load(currentVideoData.getVideoThumbnail()).into(holder.imgThumbnailVideo);
        holder.txtTitleVideo.setText(currentVideoData.getVideoTitle());
        holder.txtCountVideo.setText(currentVideoData.getVideoCount());
        holder.txtDateVideo.setText(currentVideoData.getVideoDate());

    }

    //=================== getItemCount   ============================= //
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return videoDataList.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show `ArchiveRecyclerAdapter` class code also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
adapter = new ArchiveRecyclerAdapter(ArchiveActivity.this , videoDataList);
archiveRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Probably these lines in `loadMore()` method causing issue because every time when `onLoadMore` method called setting new Adapter object to `archiveRecyclerView`.

Currently `adapter` object and `setAdapter` is already created and called  in `onCreate` method, so no need to use these lines again.

Comment: Thanks for your solution :@

Comment: @kianarahimi: Welcome Dear :)